# Are CSS3 transitions disabled when element is hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have noticed that (using jQuery in Chrome 43) transitions are disabled when the element has `display: none`. Is this standarized behavior on all browsers, a feature of jQuery, or is it something that cannot be relied on in production?

The transition is enabled when the CSS statements to be animated are changed in a deferred function. [Take a look at this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cy9qmme5/3/). Uncomment line 3 ***or*** 6 to see it for yourself.

---

***SOLUTION:***

This behavior cannot be relied upon in production as it seems to be a product of optimization/design choices rather than specification (as per @Andriy Horens answer). Instead you should turn on and off the animation (`transition-property: none`) *with a class*. Failing to use a class rendered it unreliable for me in Chrome 43. Chrome did also require separate frames (defer the code with a timeout of 0) to update some CSS statements. Just defer anything related to animations if you want to save development time.

Comment: came across similar in safari 6

Comment: How do you know if the transitions are disabled if you can't see them?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Take a look at the JSFiddle. If you uncomment line 6 it will set `opacity: 1` instantly without any transition.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me using Chrome 43. If I just uncomment line 6 it still animates the box in.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Correct. The box animates in, however, it animates out instantaneously, so that it is invisible for two seconds.

Comment: Since your fiddle uses `display:none` I assume that's what you mean when you say `display:hidden` in your question — you don't mean `visibility:hidden` (you may want to edit)

Comment: What's more interesting is that transitions are disabled when `display` is changed from `none` in the same frame as the property change. https://jsfiddle.net/620ukmzd/

Comment: @StephenP Thank you! I probably wrote `hidden` because I wrote "hidden" in the title. I meant `display: none` like it is in the JSFiddle.

Comment: @Jan Yes, that is why I am wondering whether or not this is a reliable behavior in production.

Comment: Yes and no. You can expect this to be a reliable behavior *for now*. But since this doesn't sound like the expected behavior to me, but rather like a bug, I would expect that it's possibly liable to change and interpretation from each browser. If you want to specifically disable animations, I'd advise to do so explicitly.

Comment: @Jan It has been like this for at least a year (noticed this roughly a year ago). I am working on a CSS3 picture gallery and need to turn off transitions, change the `opacity` to `0`, update the image `src`, turn on transitions and change the `opacity` to `1`. However with this behavior there is no need to turn off transitions as long as the element has `display: hidden`. I guess I'll turn off transitions just to be sure.

Comment: Yeah like you say, it works. I just wouldn't 100% count on it reliably continuing to do so.

Comment: @Jan It is not reliable at all. When setting `transition-property` to `none` it seems to take a semi-random number of milliseconds to apply. I suspect this unfortunately has got to do with the CPU speed as it only happens on my laptop.

Comment: I have made it work reliably with `display: none`. However the transitions behave incorrectly when switching to a different tab and switching back again.

Comment: I meant the `display:none` disabling animations behavior. I wouldn't rely on that continuing to disable animations for all browsers/future versions, since to me it seems like a bug.

Comment: @Jan I agree, but it is _the only_ reliable way of doing it for now that I can think of, as setting `transition-property: none` isn't reliable, unfortunately.

Comment: ...and neither is setting the `transition...` properties in a class and removing that class for the element entirely? Having a `.transitions-enabled` class if you will?

Comment: @Jan I have not tried this. I will try this a bit later and report whether it works.

Comment: @Jan If I use the class "technique" with _one_ matching element, it suddenly works perfectly. However, if the selector matches more than one element, it starts lagging and behaving poorly again. I have gone through the code many times, and it is very simple, so I doubt there are any errors in the code.. Everything works perfectly all the time in Internet Explorer 11...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

### Display

> In addition to the many different display box types, the value **none** lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use **none**, all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.

So i think elements with display set to none will not be rendered at all across all browsers and therefore transition or any other visual effect won't be applied.

You can also test yourself by subscribing to `transitionend` event:

```
$(element).on("transitionend", function () {
     console.log("transition ended");
});
```

---

**Update:**

It is also per [w3c](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-display/#box) specification:

> And some values (such as display:none, display: contents, and box-suppress: discard) cause the element and/or its descendants to not generate any boxes at all.

Where boxes are visual representations of element. And transition is definitely a part of visual representation as it also can affect layout e.g. when you change relative position of element with transition applied.

---

Here is one more example of how different are animations of elements with `display : none` and `visibility : hidden` in other words of rendered element and not-rendered one.

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0uyjg2ex/2/)

Comment: In other words browsers that save resources wherever possible will work like this. But there is no standard specifying that this is how transitions are going to behave. Are you sure about the `transitionstart` event? https://jsfiddle.net/cy9qmme5/4/

Comment: Yes, i'm on Chrome 43 and there is no console output (as expected), however if you try to change `display: none` to `visibility: hidden` you'll still have hidden element but all transition will be applied.

Comment: Shouldn't the event trigger when the element is transitioning from `opacity` `0` to `1`?

Comment: Hmm interesting it does work for me with `transitionend` event! Check yourself - https://jsfiddle.net/cy9qmme5/5/

Comment: Okay one last update, this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219025/javascript-is-there-a-css-transition-start-event) says that there is no standard `transitionstart` event, not counting one implemented only by IE10+ and `transitionend` is one you should use as it is part of w3c transition spec.