# CSS3 animations - animationstart event won't fire when using transition:

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Given the following:

```
.slide{
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

and

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('animationstart', function() {
  alert(1);
}, false);
```

the event won't fire.

However, if the CSS is :

```
.slide {
  animation: slide 1s infinite
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to { 
    transform: translateX(-100px);
   }
}
```

**It does fire.**

How come? It's an animation in both cases, however, in the first case we don't use the keyframes which have other negative consequences.

Isn't this an error in how browsers have implemented this feature?

**Here is an example for the first:**

http://jsbin.com/hizoyopimu/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

And second:

http://jsbin.com/yegidehusi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Is there something equivalent?

Comment: No, a transition is not an animation

Comment: @vals how is it not? it animates, does it not? are there any difference in performance?

Comment: But an animation has an exact definition, it's not "something that animates"

Comment: But transitions are so much more correctly implemented. they can even go in reverse without any hassle. So there is no way around this?

Comment: Why do you need this event?

Comment: Animations (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) the term, connected to the `@keyframes` action. Therefore, you should not expect the event `animationstart` during the simple transition, defined in CSS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR (Short Answer):**

As of now there is no event that gets fired during the start of a transition. Transitions always happen only when a triggering condition is satisfied and so the event which triggers the transition can roughly be considered as equivalent to the `transitionstart` event.

In the below snippet, I have added a user-defined function (`transitionStart`) which gets called right after the `.addClass('slide')` and this is kind of equivalent to `transitionstart`.

```js
/* For Animation Start */
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.animated').removeClass('hide').addClass('slide');
}, 1000);

$('.animated').bind('animationstart webkitAnimationStart', function() {
  console.log('Animation Started');
});

/* For Transition Start */
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.animated').removeClass('hide').addClass('slide');
  transitionStart();
}, 1000);

function transitionStart(){
  console.log('Transition Started');
}
```

```css
.element {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.element.animated.hide {
  display: none;
}
.animated.slide {
  animation: slide 1s infinite
}
@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
}
.element.transitioned.hide {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.transitioned.slide {
  transition: all 2s ease-in 0s;
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Element with Animation</h3>
<div class='element hide animated'>
  box
</div>

<h3>Element with Transition</h3>
<div class='element hide transitioned'>
  box
</div>
```

A `transitionend` event is available and can be used to identify the ending point of the transition and then perform any required function calls or other process. The below snippet has a sample for this.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.transitioned').removeClass('hide').addClass('slide');
  transitionStart();
}, 1000);

function transitionStart(){
  console.log('Transition Started');
}

$('.transitioned').bind('transitionend', function() {
  console.log('Transition Ended');
});
```

```css
.element {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.element.transitioned.hide {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.transitioned.slide {
  transition: all 2s ease-in 0s;
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Element with Transition</h3>
<div class='element hide transitioned'>
  box
</div>
```

---

**Long Answer:**

First of all, `animation` and `transition` are not same even though they produce a gradual change of the values assigned to the properties. Below are some key differences:

- Transitions can have only one start state and one end state. Intermediate states are beyond the control of a developer and is determined by the UA. When using animations, the developer can specify as many intermediate states between the start and end state as required.
- Transitions cannot start/be triggered automatically unlike animations. Transitions are started only when there is a change of state through user interaction like (`hover`, `click` etc) or when some extra class is added to the element through JS. Animations can start automatically when the page is loaded.
- There is no looping or iteration for transitions (unlike animations). A transition can run only once.

You can read more about the differences between them and when one should be used in [this article](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2300569&seqNum=2).

---

[Animation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-events) (`animationstart`, `animationend` etc) will not fire for your first case (the one where you are using `transition`) because there is no `animation` or valid `@keyframe` rule specified on the element.

> **As per W3C Spec**
>
> Any animation for which both a valid keyframe rule and a non-zero duration are defined will run and generate events; this includes animations with empty keyframe rules.

---

As per current spec there is no specific event that is fired when a `transition` is started unlike when an `animation` starts. In other words, there is no `transitionstart` event. Currently there is only one transition event (`transitionend`) that is implemented. ([W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-events)).

I cannot say for sure if it was a conscious decision to not implement `transitionstart` event or it was just a miss. But the fact is that we don't have an equivalent one at present.

Personally, I do not see this as a big miss because the developer should know the exact trigger points for a `transition` (like the addition of a new class via JS or through user interaction events which can also be detected via JS). So, we can always say that a transition has started at the very same instant when the trigger condition was satisfied. For your case, the `transition` has started at the same time at which the `.addClass('slide')` is executed. So, whatever extra steps you want to do (or) functions that you want to call can be called directly after the `.addClass('slide')` is executed.

**Points to note:**

- The above way of finding a transition's start is not 100% equivalent to the `animationstart` event. The reason is because the `animationstart` event is fired only after the `animation-delay` that is set has expired. In your snippet there is no delay for either the animation or transition and hence this is not a big issue. If you do have a delay then you'd have to get the value of the `transition-delay` property and execute another time-out before calling the required functions (or) actions.
- I remember reading earlier in another article that IE10 had `transitionstart` event but it is non-standard and hence is not recommended.

Comment: Good points, but in my code, I can't get transitionend to start either, which is really what I am after here. Plus, as you point out, the delay wouldn't be possible, and there wouldn't be a smooth way of adding a class on start/end .. for complete hide or show. It can possibly be done in other ways, including hardcoding the delay, but we can probably all agree that this is not the ideal way.

Comment: It would be much much nicer to have a globally ready class that is always added when started and ended. The thing with animations is that they always require a start state, bulky to repeat or integrate with others, obtrusive to declare and most of the time plain redundant. transitions work fine for 99% of my cases and is so much more elegant to use and reuse.

Comment: Here is an example for animationend which is not working: http://jsbin.com/xaxasocena/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: In reference to: " In other words, there is no transitionstart event. Currently there is only one transition event (transitionend) that is implemented."

Comment: @momo: I am trying to take in your comments but for the demo you had posted, you should use `transitionend` event with the event listener (`$('.element')[0].addEventListener('transitionend', function()`) and not `animationend`. The `transitionend` event does work for me on Chrome.

Comment: Transitionstart seems to be implement in IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219025/javascript-is-there-a-css-transition-start-event

Comment: Yes @momo. I mentioned that in answer also but it is non standard and may get dropped anytime.

Answer (score 4):

Now in 2020:

When using transitions, you have to use `transition` events instead of `animation` events.

[Compatability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionstart_event#Browser_compatibility) (works even in Edge v42)

```
  yourElement.addEventListener("transitionstart", () => {
      alert("transitionstart");
  });
```

---

**Example:**

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");
  
  div1.addEventListener("click", () => {
      div1.classList.toggle("transition");
 });
 
  div1.addEventListener("transitionstart", () => {
      console.log("transitionstart");
    });
```

```css
.div1{
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: darkseagreen;
  display:inline-block;
}

.div1.transition{
transform: translateX(100px);
}

.div1.transition:after{
content: " again, when transition stopps!";
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"> CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. Although you have specified animationstart for a listener , you have also defined the animation in css to be infinite which will cause the alert to fire only on the **first** initial start of the infinite loop . If you want to detect the animation on every stop/start/repeat cycle: one option would be looping the animation with javascript instead of infinite css. Hopefully this helps your research.

```
.slide {
        animation: slide 1s infinite
}

@keyframes slide {
        from {
                transform: translateX(0);
        }
        to { 
                transform: translateX(100px);
        }
}
```

JS

```
var x = document.querySelector('.slide');

x.addEventListener('animationstart',function(){
  alert(1)

},false)
```

Comment: That wasn't the question and you basically reposted what I have already stated, that your answer already works. It is animation through transition thast does not.