# Firing event listeners inside a transitionend event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a `mouseover` event listener to fire only when a css transition has ended. I tried alerting a random message when the css transition ends, and it does work as intended (only showing the message when it ends). But for some reason, the `mouseover` event works even before the transition ends.

Below is my javascript. Thanks in advance guys.

```
mapContainer.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
    mapContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){ 
        if(e.clientX >= 200 && e.clientX <= 600){
            removeClass(mapContainer, "map-right");
            addClass(mapContainer, "map-left");
        } else if (e.clientX >= 900){
            removeClass(mapContainer, "map-left");
            addClass(mapContainer, "map-right");        
        } else {
            removeClass(mapContainer, "map-left");
            removeClass(mapContainer, "map-right");
        }
    });
});
```

UPDATE: I used a Z-Index hack heh... which surprsingly works... at least for what I'm trying to achieve. Not sure if it's good in practice. But basically I apply a Z-Index of 0 on the map container in CSS, and when the container is active, I use setTimeout() to increase the Z-Index, and set the interval to 3 seconds so the Z-index doesn't kick in until the transition ends.

**Javascript**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    campaignContainer.style.zIndex = "3";
    mapContainer.style.zIndex = "3";
}, 3000);
```

**CSS**

```
.map-container {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(2) rotate(30deg);
    transition: all 1.2s linear;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to fire an event (simulate/trigger a `mouseover` event) or you want to listen for a `mouseover` event on a node only after the `animationend` has fired (so listen for `mouseover` only after the animation has completed)?

Comment: hey david! I want to listen for a mouseover event AFTER the animation has completed :) should I use `animationend` instead of `transitionend`? I'm using transition in the CSS, not animation with keyframes **EDIT** just tried `animationend` and it didn't work

Comment: `addEventListener` does what it says; it adds an event listener. That listener listens from the time you add it until the page is unloaded, or [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) is called. If that transition runs multiple times, you're adding multiple listeners to the same event. You'll need some way of removing the event listener when you don't want it to run anymore.

Comment: ah thank you Mike! i just noticed that's exactly my problem. the `transitionend` only fires once after the page has loaded. I'm trying to use `removeEventListsener` when an exit button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something which will work once per transition:

```js
var transitioned = document.getElementById("transition");
var show = document.getElementById("show");
var hasEnded = false;

transitioned.addEventListener("transitionend", function(evt){
 console.log("end")
    hasEnded = true;
});

transitioned.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt){
    if(hasEnded) {
        console.log("Mousemoving");
    }
});
```

```css
#transition {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 1s linear;  
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
#transition:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="transition">
Hover me!
</div>
```

Also, for IE10 and above exlusively, you can also add

```
transitioned.addEventListener("transitionstart", function(evt){
    hasEnded = false;
});
```

Read about polyfill for `transitionstart`:

- [MadeByMike codepen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219025/javascript-is-there-a-css-transition-start-event#answer-29196041)
- [Javascript: Is there a CSS transition start event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219025/javascript-is-there-a-css-transition-start-event#answer-29196041) SO question.

Comment: hey wscourge, thanks for sharing. so I just noticed that the `transitionend` only fires once when the page loads. it won't fire a second time and just immediately fires the `mousemove` after the first time. I assume i have to use `removeEventListener` to reset `transitionend`?

Comment: Well, that's why I added reference to `transitionstart`. If you add another listener listening to `transitionstart` on the same element and inside it's `fn()` set the `hasEnded` variable to `false`, everything inside `mousemove` would stop, because nothing happens in it while `hasEnded` is not `true`. But, `transitionstart`'s support is weak, so it needs polyfill for most of the browsers (it doesn't for IE10 and above), and that's what links in the bottom of my answer stand for.

Comment: hey just wanted to update. I used a `Z-Index` hack heh... which surprsingly works... at least for what I'm trying to achieve. Not sure if it's good in practice. But basically I apply a `Z-Index` of 0 on the map container in CSS, and when the container is active, I use `setTimeout()` to increase the Z-Index, and set the interval to 3 seconds (the time it takes for the transition to end).